# Jasper bar chart: unable to show labels

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I'm struggling with Jasper to display value labels on top of the bars of my chart. What I want to generate:

[image: bar chart with labels]

I use Jaspersoft Studio, and I checked the "Show Labels" box in "Chart Plot" tab. For test purpose, I use some sort of red and violet for the item label font color and background color, which should be quite visible on the bar chart.

My jrxml file looks like this:

```
        <barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="false">
            <plot backcolor="#FFFFFF" labelRotation="0.0">
                <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#6D74BC"/>
            </plot>
            <itemLabel color="#E86841" backgroundColor="#C429B5">
                <font fontName="Arial" size="25" isBold="true" isItalic="true" isUnderline="true" isStrikeThrough="true"/>
            </itemLabel>
            <categoryAxisFormat labelRotation="0.0">
                <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#6D74BC" verticalTickLabels="true" axisLineColor="#6D74BC">
                    <labelFont>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    </labelFont>
                    <tickLabelFont>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    </tickLabelFont>
                </axisFormat>
            </categoryAxisFormat>
            <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA[$P{unitFact}]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
            <valueAxisFormat>
                <axisFormat labelColor="#6D74BC" tickLabelColor="#6D74BC" verticalTickLabels="false" axisLineColor="#6D74BC">
                    <labelFont>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    </labelFont>
                    <tickLabelFont>
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    </tickLabelFont>
                </axisFormat>
            </valueAxisFormat>
        </barPlot>
```

I also tried to use a customizer, based on some SO questions:

```
@Override
public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, JRChart jrChart) {
    CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot)jFreeChart.getPlot();
    plot.getRenderer()
        .setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(
            ItemLabelAnchor.OUTSIDE12,
            TextAnchor.BOTTOM_CENTER));
}
```

I couldn't make it work, I have the bar chart above but without the 110/760 labels.

What should I do in order to show these values?

Comment: wheredo u set ur customize method?, I only use the jrxml part. thanks

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña The customize method is inside a class that implements `JRChartCustomizer`. It's been a while so I can't tell how exactly this class is used by Jasper, but you should check the doc about chart customizers or ask your own question if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new bar chart from scratch and everything worked fine with the same config. After some digging, I figured out that when I first created the initial chart, I put a blank string as the expression to use for labels, thinking that it was the axis label (I didn't want the Value axis' labels to show up). I fixed that, and the first bar chart worked as well. Dumb way to lose days of work.